# Bootstrap tooltip style only showing up if the page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with my bootstrap tooltip.  If you visit the page from another page, the tooltip will not have the bootstrap styling.  But if the page is reloaded, the styling works fine.

This is my rendered head when you first visit a page:

```
 <link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap.min.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/font-awesome-ie7.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/font-awesome-ie7.min.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/font-awesome.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/font-awesome.min.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/style.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/style.min.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/social-share.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/index.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/assets/vendor/modernizr.js?body=1"></script>
```

The head stays the same if the page is reloaded...

Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Is the page change "natural"? Or are you using a AJAXing in content? If so the event handlers could be getting unset. A link to the page or a demo recreating the full scenario would help.

Comment: Can you post your code for the tooltip init?

Comment: I'm not using that. Just the bootstrap.js file.  This is how its called.  = image_tag @store_front.header(:background), "data-placement" => "left", "data-toggle" => "tooltip", :title => "Click here to edit your header          Recomended size: '700x394px'"

Comment: There might be some conflict going on. Check your console for any javascript errors. 

Or you can set up a test page for us to further help you. One thing I saw, is you have duplicate css files linked. For example, bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css don't have to be both linked. Just bootstrap.min.css is fine, assuming that theses are the same files, with just a minimized version.